# How whatsapp/telegram ensures incoming call notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am making a VoIP app. How do I ensure incoming call notifications, even if the app is in background? Google FCM works only when app is in foreground (presumably due to android battery optimisation). What did Whatsapp and Telegram do to ensure nearly 100% incoming calls notifications?

`onMessageReceived` method is not getting invoked when app is in background.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    }
}
```

**PS**
While going through [Telegram's codebase](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) I found that they always keep running their app in foreground

`<service android:name=".BringAppForegroundService" android:enabled="true"/>`

Is that how they solved notifications or is there more than what meets the eye?

Comment: have you tried data only messages in firebase notification response ?

Comment: @DäñishShärmà Yes tried it `user.sendCloudMessage({customData: data, priority: "high"})`. Where data is `{
      "sinch": {
        ...
        "PushData": pushData,
        ...
      }
    }`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, Did you get the real cause for this issue?. The data message is not always delivered in Xiaomi/Huawei phone, but telegram/WhatsApp calls are working.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your backend developer and tell him not to use notification object in firebase notification. Only send **data** object with **to** parameter.

Don't send from server **Notification** object. Because if you use `notification` object in `json`, your app will not show push notification when your app is in background.

for e.g.

```
{
    "to": "e1w6hEbZn-8:APA91bEUIb2JewYCIiApsMu5JfI5Ak...",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Cool offers. Get them before expiring!",
        "title": "Flat 80% discount",
        "icon": "appicon"
    }
}
```

Your backend developer must be sending json like this:

```
{ 
"data": {
"score": "5x1",
"time": "15:10"
},
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

If you use `data only messages`, **onMessageReceived()** method will be called in both the cases, even your app is in `foreground` or `background`. Then just get the response by using `key values`.

```
 @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  ...
   Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

  //you can get your text message here.
  String text= data.get("text");
 ...
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue and it was resolved after using data only messages. Now app notifications works in both the cases foreground and background but if the app is killed by swiping, in that case if you do not get the notifications then add these permissions in manifest "uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK". Please refer these links 1) https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/368 2) https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/365

Comment: com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is deprected for FCM, it was used by GCM